# Extended abstract

Tags: thesis, masters, abstract

I am writing my master thesis.

I also have to write an extended abstract in english.

Could you explain to me how many parts of the master thesis the extended abstract should contain?

Do I have to include the theorems? And their proofs or just an idea of the proof?

Do I have to include the corollarys that are used to prove the theorems?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Unfortunately, I'm not sure we stranger on the internet can answer your questions: what is expected in your thesis will depend on both your field and your institution.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of an abstract is to tell people what they'll get out of reading the rest of the paper. It doesn't serve as a substitute for the paper. Theorems -- in a readably summarized form -- are a reasonable thing to include, if they're the main contribution. If there's something particularly unexpected and exotic about the form of the proofs, you could describe that too, but generally "we show such-and-such" is enough for the abstract.

Comment: Ok... And how long should it be?

Comment: @MaryStar Ask your advisor. There's no general standard. As an academic, though, I don't see the point of an abstract that takes me more than two minutes to read. I've got like thirty other papers to get through that day.

Comment: @Sneftel, the question is about *extended* abstracts for which I've seen requests of up to 3 or 4 pages for a 15-page paper. Some conferences use them, with peer review, to choose papers. Some other venues use them like executive summaries of theses, etc.